# JSFL - Running an action on publish

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, jsfl

I want my JSFL to be run every time an FLA is published so I can create meta-data on publish time (like the date-time in which it was published).

I cannot find an event or similar to hook a call to my JSFL code.

---

Just for anyone that is still interested in this:
I found a way of doing this, it requires xJSFL but from there it's really simple.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here and describe what you've tried? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

There is not much context to give, I haven't started coding since I'm not even sure if what I want to do is possible.

I want to 'listen' for the publish event in the Flash IDE and run an arbitrary piece of JSFL when such an event happens. I went through the JSFL spec and couldn't find such an event, I was wondering if anyone else has tried to solve this problem and succeeded.